solution verification: Is $K(s)$ holomorphic on $\Bbb C$?
Consider the Mellin integral
$$K(s)=\int_{1/2}^1 \zeta\bigg(-\frac{1}{\log x}\bigg)~x^{s-1}~dx  $$
Where $\zeta(\cdot)$ is the Riemann zeta function defined for real $1/e<x<1.$ $K(s)$ is holomorphic on $\Bbb C$ due to the convergence on $-\infty<\Re(s)<\infty$.
We have the classical product representation
$$ K(s)= \int_{1/2}^1 \bigg(\prod_{p ~\mathrm{prime}} \frac{1}{1-p^{\frac{1}{\log x}}}\bigg)~x^{s-1}~dx $$
we can further analyze the integrand and see that there is a geometric series involved which we re-introduce the sum
$$  = \int_{1/2}^1  \prod_{p~ \mathrm{prime}} \bigg(1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty p^{\frac{n}{\log x}}\bigg)~x^{s-1}~dx  $$
some basic algebra yields
$$= \int_{1/2}^1 \prod_{p~ \mathrm{prime}} \bigg(1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{\frac{n\log p}{\log x}}\bigg)~x^{s-1}~dx$$

Is $K(s)$ indeed holomorphic on $\Bbb C$?

Further attempt:
$K(s)$ is holomorphic on $\Bbb C$. The integral converges due to more than exponential decay $x\to 0$. Holomorphic is automatic because $x^{s}$ is holomorphic in $s$.
We can look at a Cahen Mellin type integral and we can compare it to the meromorphic extension of $\zeta(-1/\log x)$ which is known to be a composition with the Riemann zeta, hence admits a meromorphic extension to all of $\Bbb C$ aside from a pole at $x=1/e$ and a branch cut due to the logarithm.
Due to the identity theorem the Cahen Mellin approach and the meromorphic extension of $\zeta(-1/\log x)$ should agree.
Let's take a look at a Cahen Mellin type integral:
$$\zeta\bigg(-\frac{1}{\log x}\bigg)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} K(s) x^{-s}~ds $$
where we must pick up the residues of the integrand.
Take $-\infty<c<\infty$. There are no poles in this region since $K$ is entire. I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

How is $K$ integrable at $1/e$?

Just note that near $1/e$ we have the expansion $1/(-1/\log x-1)$ (plus continuous stuff) and then if $xe=1+y$ you get a $1/y$ term which is n ot integrable or you change variables $-1/\log x=u$

@Conrad ah I guess I will have to just change the 1/e to 1/2. This change will make things converge but won't destroy the main idea. Thanks for pointing that out

"we can take the product outside of the integral" -  am I missing something here? Could you add some clarification?

Have you tried using the series representation $\zeta(s)=\sum n^{-s}$?

@TravorLZH I considered that but this question isn't about $\zeta(s)$ rather $\zeta(-1/\log s)$

If you want $K$ to be the Mellin transform of $f(x)=\zeta(-1/\ln x)$, then you made a typo. You should rather define it as:$$K(s)=\int_If(x)x^{s-1}dx$$ This makes it consistent with your inversion formula which is correct.

This behavior is completely normal and is classic for Fourier/Laplace/Mellin transforms. I’ll define:
$$
f(x)=\zeta(-1/\ln x)
$$
The key is that you are not integrating over the entire domain so applying the transformation and its inverse will not give you the original function, but will set it to zero outside the domain of integration.
Take the simpler example:
$$
f(x)=1/x
$$
If you take the Mellin transform:
$$
F(s)=\int_{1/2}^1f(x)x^{s-1}dx
$$
you can compute it explicitly as:
$$
F(s)=\frac{1-2^{1-s}}{s-1}
$$
Just as in your example, $F$ is entire (removable singularity at $s=1$).
You can now consider the inverse Mellin transform:
$$
\tilde f(t)=\frac1{2\pi i}\int F(s)x^{-s}ds
$$
Indeed, since $F$ is analytic, you can take any vertical line to integrate. However, you cannot deduce that the integral is zero. Implicitly, you are assuming that you can deform the line to a circle and then contract it to get zero. This is only possible for $x\not\in(1/2,1)$ because of the essential singularities of the exponentials at infinity.
For $x<1/2$, you can deform the vertical line by closing it off at $\Re s=+\infty$. Similarly, for $x>1$, you can deform the vertical line at $\Re s=-\infty$. However, at $t\in(1/2,1)$, you are stuck as you cannot close on either side, and indeed, the value of the integral is non zero.
Furthermore, for $x\in(1/2,1)$, your contour needs to have vertical asymptotes to not “upset” the essential singularity. This means that you cannot use the integral representation to analytically continue $f$ for complex $t$ since the integral will now diverge exponentially.
This is basically what is happening with you case. For $x\not\in(1/2,1)$ you do get zero, but for $x\in(1/2,1)$ you cannot deform the vertical line contour due to the essential singularity at infinity. It’s trickier to see in your case as $K$ does not have a simple analytic expression. Also, you cannot use it to recover the meromorphic extension of $\zeta$ because the contour integral diverges as soon as $x$ is not real.
Back to my toy example, if the lower bound of the integration is taken to be $0$, the ROC is now for $\Re s>1$ and:
$$
F(s)=\frac1{s-1}
$$
You now have a pole at $s=1$. By contour integration you recover the original function $f(x)=\frac1x$ but only for $x<1$. Indeed, the same trick of closing the integral works for $x>1$.
Similarly for your case, if you chose the lower bound to be $1/e$, you’ll be able to extend the integral representation all the way to the pole at $x=1/e$.
The usual way to use Mellin type integrals for meromorphic extension is to rather reason the other way around. You need to view the function you want to continue as a Mellin transform. This is how you get the usual integral representation of the zeta function that you can then meromorphically extend.
Hope this helps.

The last paragraph. If I want to continue $f$ I should take its mellin transform to obtain $\hat f$ and then use contour integration on $\hat f$ along a vertical line to continue $f$ right?

I'm slightly confused because that's what I am doing with $$\zeta\bigg(-\frac{1}{\log x}\bigg)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} K(s) x^{-s}~ds$$

No, the opposite, I was suggesting you to write it as:$$\zeta(-1/\ln s)=\int_0^\infty \phi(x)x^{s-1}dx$$This is how you get the integral representation of the gamma function (Mellin transformation of $e^{-x}$) and of the zeta function (Mellin transform of $\frac1{e^x-1}$). After all, it is the Mellin transform whose natural domain is complex, unlike the original function which is naturally supported on $\mathbb R_+$

oh I see thanks
